# rails form default value - text faded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, text, input, default

Hey I am trying to set a default value in an input box as such:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, value: 'email'  %>
</div>
```

I would like to make the email text be faded and then when the user clicks on the input box the text is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a placeholder

```
f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "email"
```